# Synchronizing sequence of emptying liquid tanks

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Unsure if this belongs to engineering, but I have following practical problem. I'll start following simplified example.

- Tank #1 volume - $50~\text{m}^3$
- Tank #2 volume - $35~\text{m}^3$
- Tank #3 volume - $15~\text{m}^3$

I am requested to maintain total rate of $5~\text{m}^3/\text{hour}$, while synchronizing discharge in order to achieve sequence of 1-2-3 tank with an interval of 10 minutes.

What I do practically is just multiplying the percentage of total cargo single tank represents with discharge rate (e.g. for tk#1 0.50x5) to calculate sequence for ending at same time and then just open valve a little bit more for tank number 1 and close a little bit for tank number 3.

My question is how to design a formula which I could use manually/in excel on the fly to input know variables

-volume of cargo in each tank to be discharged

-total discharge rate

-desired time of discharge for each tank

And obtain the discharge rate required for each tank.

Comment: I think more information is needed to solve the problem. What does "sequence of 1-2-3 with an interval of 10 minutes" mean? I would need to understand better how the discharge rates work in this case ...

Comment: By that I mean I should finish tank number 1 first, tank number 2 ten minutes after tank number 2, and then tank number 3 ten minutes after tank number 2

Comment: Okay good - then next question: Does the size of the tank have anything to do with the flow rate from it?

Comment: I realized ambiguity in my question - volume given is cargo in tank, as tank volume itself shouldn't be relevant to this question. https://ibb.co/37L8j0r is a link of real life problem (couldnt upload on above question. What I am trying to get is a solution for obtaining desires discharge rates for sequence I want, instead of manipulating valves "by feel" and then calculating everytime the expected discharging time and hoping it matches sequence.

Comment: As you can see, I have a TOTAL rate of 5k in picture I have to maintain, and then I can distribute individual tank rates however I please, so total flow rate is constant, while individual tank rates will be variables.

Comment: So is there a problem with starting with tank number 1 and keeping the rate at 5 cbm/h, then when that runs out, switch to tank 2 ... ?

Comment: Yes, because then I will discharge tank #1 in 10 hours, and then #2 7 hours later, while desired interval between fully emptying tanks is 10 minutes.

Comment: Okay so as I understand it currently, I would formulate the problem mathematically like so: I have three functions $f_1(t), f_2(t)$ and $f_3(t)$. I want
$$
f_1(t_0) = 0 \qquad f_2(t_0 + 10~\text{minutes}) = 0 \qquad f_3(t_0 + 20~\text{minutes}) = 0
$$
for some value $t_0$, and also
$$
f_1'(t) + f_2'(t) + f_3'(t) = -5 \qquad \text{for all}~0<t<t_0 + 20~\text{minutes}
$$
where the "prime" represents the derivative.
Does it seem correct?

Comment: The easiest way to investigate this would be to try linear solutions like this:
$$
f_1(t) = a(t-t_0) \qquad f_2(t) = b(t-t_0 - 10)  \qquad f_3(t) = c (t-t_0 -20)
$$
which automatically fulfills the first row of requirements ($t_0$ has the units of minutes). Then we have $a+b+c=-5$ and also the initial conditions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do (most of) the heavy lifting: Let's set the total cargo in each tank (1, 2 and 3) to be
$$
f_1(t) = 50-at
\qquad
f_2(t) = 35 - bt
\qquad
f_3(t) = 15 - ct
$$
where $a, b, c$ are some constants. These functions fulfill the required initial conditions at $t=0$. Then, we know that tank 1 should be empty at some point $t=t_0$, and tanks 2 and 3 should follow after 10 minutes each. Let's assume that $t$ has the units of minutes. Then these conditions become
$$
f_1(t_0) = 50-at_0 = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad a = \frac{50}{t_0}
$$
$$
f_2(t_0 + 10) = 35-b(t_0+10) = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad b = \frac{35}{t_0+10}
$$
$$
f_3(t_0 +20) = 15- c(t_0 + 20) =  0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad c = \frac{15}{t_0 +20}
$$
Then, we have a condition for the total discharge rate; we want the sum of the derivatives of $f_1, f_2$ and $f_3$ to equal $-5/60$ at all times. The sum of the derivatives is equal to $-a-b-c$, so we have a condition $a+b+c=5/60$. Plugging in the previous results, we get
$$
\frac{50}{t_0} + \frac{35}{t_0+10} + \frac{15}{t_0 +20} = \frac{5}{60}
$$
For positive values of $t_0$, we have a unique solution. Can you finish the problem from here?

---

Edit:

In principle, the last equation is a cubic equation for $t_0$. Since this is an engineering application, there is no need for an exact solution. A numerical solution is enough, and in this case the positive solution for the equation is
$$
t_0 \approx 1~193.54~\text{minutes} \quad \text{or}~19~\text{h}~53.5~\text{min}~
$$
This result can be obtained by drawing the graphs of the functions
$$
\begin{cases}
f(x) =& 50/x + 35/(x+10) + 15/(x+20)\\
g(x) =& 5/60
\end{cases}
$$
and finding the intersection graphically.

Using the obtained value for $t_0$, the following flow rates are obtained:
$$
a\approx 2.513~\frac{\text{m}^3}{\text{h}}
\qquad
b\approx 1.745~\frac{\text{m}^3}{\text{h}}
\qquad
c\approx 0.742~\frac{\text{m}^3}{\text{h}}
$$

Comment: Just a comment: It turns out that the value for $t_0$ is large enough that you could almost approximate $t_0+10 \approx t_0$ and $t_0 + 20 \approx t_0$. This kind of approximation would change the answer only a little bit and change the required discharge rates by less than half a $\%$ ...

Comment: So far it looks good, thanks. However, let me first it apply to few real operations (like link in comment before) and see if any questions arise before accepting this answer so I can post here in case I have any.

Comment: And yes, indeed as you say t0 is almost equal to t0+10, that's why just calculating time for discharge at same time and then opening relevant valves like half percent more or less worked out in practice, however out of curiosity I am interested in more "exact science" approach.

Comment: Okay, I might be dense, because I couldn't figure out answer from these functions (i figured out the constants, however it seems I cannot make it work) However, by trial and error I figured disch rates to be 2.51360, 1.74480 and 0.74170 cbm/h respectively for tanks #1, #2 and #3, which will finish #1 after 19hrs 53.5 min, #2 after 20 hrs 03.6 mins and #3 after 20hrs 13.6 minutes. However, I am struggling to obtain these results using above method, so any extra direction is welcome.

Comment: @Arnie I added a few notes. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

The total discharge time is just the total volume divided by the total discharge rate.

Calculate the time each tank should empty.

The discharge rate for the first tank is its volume divided by the time it should empty.

Now you have an undetermined parameter.  You can compute the total discharge from the other two tanks during the first interval, but there is nothing to tell you how to split it between them as long as neither runs dry too early.  You can compute how much has to be left in the third tank when the second runs out so it can support the whole third interval.  You could compute the drain of the third tank to get to this point when the second runs out, then just use the second to make up the difference.  That will give you the fewest adjustments.

When the first tank runs dry, compute the volume remaining in the second tank based on the discharge rate you chose in the last step.  You can now compute the discharge rate for the second tank by dividing by the time remaining until it is dry.

The third tank makes up the shortfall in both of the first two intervals, then supplies the whole discharge for the third.  It will empty at the correct time.